# GWT Composite Widget - Button clicks

Tags: java, gwt

I have made a composite widget with several buttons. How can I register those buttons that when clicked will call a method in my main class? Each button would be calling a different method in my main class.

The Widget is added to the main class root panel.

Thanks

Comment: How are you building this composite widget?1 normally if you build  composite widget you dont need to attach each of its internal widgets in its own., and why cant you assign a click handler to the button.

Comment: It would be great, if you can share some of your code. That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons in the composite widget should receive click events.

Something like the following should work (for java 8+)

```
   ...
   composite.btn1.addClickHandler(event -> myBtn1ClickMethod());
   composite.btn2.addClickHandler(event -> myBtn2ClickMethod());
}

void myBtn1ClickMethod()
{
    // code to handle the button 1 being clicked
}
```